# How does the Notoriety Wipe work?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

If I buy Notoriety Wipe for gangs or police, is that something I can only use once? Or can I use it repeatedly? Is there a limit on the number of times you can use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you can use it multiple times, but you are restricted to using it [once per hour](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/saints-row-the-third/Gang_Abilities_Upgrades#Notoriety_Wipe), and will be blocked from using it during certain missions.

Comment: Also, of note: on at least one mission I was able to use the Notoriety Wipe, but was almost immediately granted with three or four star notoriety again.

Comment: BTW: Using the Police Notoriety Wipe makes it MUCH easier to explore the military base.